# Using multiple instances of rrdcached on a single server?

Tags: cacti, graph, rrdtool, collectd, observium

I'm trying to figure out the best way to use rrdcached on a single server for multiple graphing tools. Currently I'm using cacti, observium and collectd on the same server (running CentOS 6.7) that all use rrdtool to create graphs. While following a guide I found (http://blog.best-practice.se/2014/10/using-rrdcached-with-observium.html) which works fine for just Observium I get all my graphs for cacti or collectd messed up since I define the folder with -B to my Observium RRD folder.

Any tips from people in the same situation or do I have to split up my monitoring tools between servers (which seems to be a huge waste of resources)?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing the same problem:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/rrdcached
OPTIONS="-w 1800 -z 1800 -f 3600 -s apache -l unix:/var/run/rrdcached/rrdcached.sock -j /var/tmp/ -F -b /opt/observium/rrd/"
RRDC_USER=apache
```

And for the collectd configuration:

```
<Plugin rrdcached>
    DaemonAddress "unix:/var/run/rrdcached/rrdcached.sock"
    DataDir "/var/lib/collectd"
    CreateFiles true
    CreateFilesAsync false
    CollectStatistics true
</Plugin>
```